# Before_create isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `Article` model file I have:

```
before_create   :generate_token
validates :token, presence: true
private
def generate_token
  self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```

And in my migration:

```
t.string :token, null: false
```

But now tests that create an article fail with `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Token can't be blank`. In these tests I indeed don't give a value for `token`. However, shouldn't the `before_create` method above do this automatically? It concerns test that call upon the `create` method for a new author, of which the controller method includes the line `@author.articles.create!` (so without a token value for the article).

P.S. I put the `debugger` at the top of the `generate_token` method, and it never fires for any of the tests.

Comment: `@author.articles.create!` does not create an article. `create!` should be called on the `@author` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_validation :generate_token, on: :create
   validates :token, presence: true

   private

   def generate_token
        self.token = loop do
            random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
            break random_token unless self.class.exists? random_token
        end
   end
end
```

---

A much better way is to use [`has_secure_token`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_token) (included in Rails 5; [gem](https://github.com/robertomiranda/has_secure_token) here):

```
#Gemfile
gem "has_secure_token" #-> not needed for Rails 5

#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_token
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering about `on: :create`. I have multiple methods in my `Author` model that create a new author, and in that same controller method create the first/new article for that author (`@author.articles.create()`). Would this before action automatically fire for all these different controller methods, irrespective whether they are name `create` or something else?

Comment: The `create` callback is for an object, not a method. In order for the object to be initialized / invoked, it has to be created. This is what `ActiveRecord` looks for when it calls "create". A good description of this methodology can be found in the [`new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F) docs

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use

`before_validation :generate_token, on: :create`

That will fire at exactly the time you are wanting it to and only on the initial creation, not on every save.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `before_create` to `before_validation`.

Comment: Thanks, then it indeed fires. But wouldn't it then create a new token not only when a new record is created but also everytime an existing record gets saved?